# Combining several android applications together

Tags: android, project

I am working on an android group project in college and this is the first big project many of us have worked on.
We worked on implementing several pieces of the project as completely separate projects and now are having trouble putting all of them in one application with a main page.

On the main page of the application we would have a bunch of buttons that would then go to the implemented project that we've completed (example, I click on BMI calculator on the app homepage and it goes the the bmi calculator screen).

Any efficient way of going about this that can be explained in an easy to follow manner? I'm still a newbie programmer :)

Just to clarify, I don't want it so that it just launches a BMI calculator app from the main app, the entire code base is supposed to exist under one app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can have a main project and several other projects declared as library projects.
In build time, library projects are pulled into the main project and only one apk will exist as the output.

The library projects are almost the same as an usual android project. You can have java packages, res folder, lib folder, etc.

Check [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects) for the official description.
Check [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html) for a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Look into making the other applications as [`Android Library`](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html)-projects, and listing all necessary components on your `AndroidManifest.xml` on your parent project.

Another way would just give the option for the user to install these applications as separate and have a logice (`PackageManager`) check if specific application exists or is installed and then enabling navigation buttons or disabling components and invoke them via Intents.